# Нужно ли в этом предложении тире?

Tags: пунктуация

При активном росте поливают чаще, при снижении роста - наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

**При активном росте поливают чаще, при снижении роста** [поливают] **наоборот** (то есть — реже).

*В неполных предложениях на месте пропущенных членов предложения или их частей **ставится тире*** (значение пропущенного члена восстанавливается из первой части предложения).
[**§ 16. Тире в неполном предложении**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105)

*...в одиночку напился пьяным, после чего куда-то пошел, а куда — не помнит, где-то еще пил старку, а где — не помнит, где-то валялся под забором, а где — не помнит опять-таки.*
(М.А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита)

***При активном росте поливают чаще, при снижении роста — наоборот*.**

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. Пропущено подразумеваемое "поливают реже".

Answer (score 1):

**Замечание по поводу употребления слова *наоборот*.**

Мне кажется, в предложениях с этим словом ситуация чаще объясняется подробно, чтобы читатель не слишком задумывался: наоборот — это как?

Например:  **При активном росте поливают чаще, при снижении роста количество поливов, наоборот, уменьшают.**

Поэтому вариант с кратким *наоборот* нужно использовать продуманно.

**Примеры для сравнения:**

Некоторые компании начали выходить из тени, а некоторые, **наоборот**, скрывают истинное положение дел.

Давай так: в первом отделении я дирижирую ― ты играешь Моцарта, во втором ― **наоборот**.